# Fish shell script : getting a precise random number

Tags: python, shell, fish

Basically, I want my greeting message (fish_greeting.fish) to display either one ASCII art or the other (a cat or a squid). So, I need to pick a random integer.
But the random function in Fish doesn't seem to take parameters (i.e random(1,4)).
So I made this in Python, but I don't know how to call it from my fish script.

Any idea? Fish shell is a wonderful shell, sadly no very documented compared to Bash (which I don't like) and zsh (awesome, but not like fish)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `math` to do arithmetic. For example:

```
if [ (math (random)'%2') -eq 1 ]
    squid
else
    cat
end
```